# Facebook Chat using XMPPFramework on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook, xmpp

Does someone already created an iPhone app that connect to the Facebook chat server using their X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication mechanism and XMPPFramework ?

I have no idea how to start, any code sample would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've you checked out Facebook doc ? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

I've integreted they're library to connect, post and access user infos on ios : http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/

You could also check out xmppframework for iPhone : http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone

Comment: Thank you. FBconnect does not cover chat and of course, xmppframework's wiki is my today's best friend but the only code mention there does not work anymore :-(

Comment: XMPPFramework now works with Facebook's latest OAuth2 changes.